# Getting git branch name inside TFS build

Tags: git, msbuild

I have a CI build definition (TFS 2013) triggered by commits to several branches (it is a git repository). I would like to use the branch name inside build process to copy results to the right place. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your own CodeActivity Like this...

you need the IBuildDetail BuildDetail as InArgument.

```cs
string branch = null;
string commit;

var environmentVariable = BuildDetail.Get(context);
if (environmentVariable != null && !BuildSourceVersion.TryParseGit(environmentVariable.SourceGetVersion, out branch, out commit))
{
    var defaultSourceProvider = environmentVariable.BuildDefinition.GetDefaultSourceProvider();
    if (BuildSourceProviders.IsGit(defaultSourceProvider.Name))
    {
        branch = BuildSourceProviders.GetProperty(defaultSourceProvider.Fields, BuildSourceProviders.GitProperties.DefaultBranch);
    }
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(branch))
{
    throw new Exception("Could not find Branch");
}

Branch.Set(context, branch.Substring(branch.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) + 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess this would work. In the end, I choose scripting, but if we decide to use TFS infrastructure more, I will hapily use your solution.

Comment: This worked great. In F# I used `let _, branch, commit = BuildSourceVersion.TryParseGit x.SourceGetVersion`. Added as an extension in SourceLink.Tfs. https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink/commit/058e071583578d22bcb2e0a87ede4c7b382b4279

Comment: Do you open the `GitTemplate.xaml` and add a code activity and just plop this code in there?

Answer (score 1):

There is whole `.git` folder accessible during the build, so I can look into the file `.git/HEAD` using PowerShell. There may be only commit hash (detached HEAD regime), and then some more git calls are required to find out where I really am. All in all, the other answer is probably cleaner.

Comment: Hi Lukáš, did you manage to find branch name from .git/HEAD? I would prefer this solution instead if creating own CodeActivity. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, you can get all branch names that are currently on the commit using `git branch --all --contains` and this can be sufficient for your usecase.